# With several ROIs in an image, how can I send the ROI to the back

Tags: dm-script

When I have several ROIs in an image, they can overlap and sometimes the smaller one gets lost behind the bigger one.  However, one of the is on "top" and the other is "below."  I have the ID of the ROI, but I am missing the command ROI_ID.ROISendToBack() or similar.

Any trick available?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of *ROI*s on a display can not be the property of an individual *ROI*, but it is a property of the thing 'containing' the *ROI*s. That's why you search for the command at the wrong place. It is not a command of the *ROI* object, but of the *ImageDisplay* object.

Each *ImageDisplay* contains a "list" of its *ROI*s and you want to change the order in that list.

The commands for specifying the "order" of *ROI*s on an *ImageDisplay* are

[image: ROI order commands]

There is no command to "move" a ROI, but you can simple remove and re-add it.

```
image img := RealImage( "Dummy",4, 350, 350)
img = iradius
img.ShowImage()
imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

ROI roi1 = NewROI()
roi1.ROISetRectangle( 100, 100, 200, 200 )
roi1.ROISetVolatile(0)
roi1.ROISetColor(1,0,0)
roi1.ROISetDrawFilled(1)
roi1.ROISetFillProperties(0.2,0.1,0,0)

ROI roi2 = NewROI()
roi2.ROISetRectangle( 125, 125, 225, 225 )
roi2.ROISetVolatile(0)
roi2.ROISetColor(0,1,0)
roi2.ROISetDrawFilled(1)
roi2.ROISetFillProperties(0.2,0,0.1,0)

ROI roi3 = NewROI()
roi3.ROISetRectangle( 150, 150, 250, 250 )
roi3.ROISetVolatile(0)
roi3.ROISetColor(0,0,1)
roi3.ROISetDrawFilled(1)
roi3.ROISetFillProperties(0.2,0,0,0.1)

disp.ImageDisplayAddROI( roi1 )
disp.ImageDisplayAddROI( roi2 )
disp.ImageDisplayAddROI( roi3 )

OKDialog( "Now send blue to the bottom" )
disp.ImageDisplayDeleteROI( roi3 )
disp.ImageDisplayAddROIAtBeginning( roi3 )

OKDialog( "Now send red to front" )
disp.ImageDisplayDeleteROI( roi1 )
disp.ImageDisplayAddROIAtEnd( roi1 )
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: BTW, there is an example on ROI ordering in the F1 help documentation of later GMS versions. (Section: "Example Scripts/ROIs" --> ROI properties --> "Changing z-ordering of ROIs on a display)